# Read most recent UDP packet by disabling SO_RCVBUF in Java DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I need to read the most recent incoming UDP packet, regardless of dropped packets in between reads.  Incoming packets are coming in 3x faster than the maximum application processing speed.  In an attempt to achieve this, I used `setReceiveBufferSize(int size)` of Java's `DatagramSocket` class to set the `SO_RCVBUF` to be the same size as my expected packet in bytes.

However, there is still a three packet delay before I get the most recent packet (and if the incoming rate is 10x the receive rate, there is a 10 packet delay).  This suggests that `SO_RCVBUF` contains more than just the newest packet.

First, are the units of `setReceiveBufferSize(int size)` in bytes?  It is not explicitly stated in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize%28int%29).  Second, is there a way to disable `SO_RCVBUF` so that I only receive the most recent incoming packet?  For example, zero is an illegal argument to the function, but I could theoretically set the receive buffer size to one.

Comment: Well, remember that sockets keeps the _oldest_ data , not the newest. If one packet reaches the socket, that will be buffered until you read it - you can't change that behavior. (and newer packets arriving will be dropped if there is no room in the socket buffers)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know that.  Is there any way to clear the SO_RCVBUF right before a read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like an unusual problem ;)

i would recommend to split your application into separate threads:

- reciever (minimal work, no parsing/etc)

  - handles the incoming packets and puts the last read object into an asyncronous variable
- processing (from what you wrote, looks like this takes a long time)

  - reads the object from the asyncronous space, and processes it (don't forget to ignore the previous)

if you need to hack things like SO_RCVBUF, i think you should step a bit closer to the io processing subsystem with C/C++

Comment: Why? Most things like SO_RCVBUF can be hacked perfectly well from Java.

Comment: yes, it can but but i think you shouldn't run into problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

You've done exactly the wrong thing. Set the receive buffer as large as possible. 512k for example. Setting it low only increases the probability of dropped packets. And either speed up the receiving code or slow down the sending code. There's no point in sending packets that can't be received.

Comment: Did you read the question?  Increasing the buffer size wouldn't help me if I don't care about dropping packets.  Ideally I would have no buffer so that the receive function pulls directly from the wire.

Comment: Did you read the answer? Reducing the buffer size won't help you either. The most recent packets are the ones that will be dropped. If you're trying to read them you have to keep the buffer with plenty of room in it, which means increasing it, and read it as fast as you can.